# Create menu in main layout like in action bar

Tags: java, android

I want to know is it possible to create menu like this?

[image: example]

Comment: just google it as Accordion effect in android check this link http://www.wardnus.com/2015/01/animated-accordion-for-android-4-part-1.html

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your screenshot is of an `ExpandableListView`, or possibly a `RecyclerView` that uses [a library to add expandable contents](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/199?sort=created).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's called Expandable List View.